# MUI Rating Custom Tooltip to increase the rendering performance

Tags: performance, material-ui, tooltip, rating

I am trying to show tooltips when the user selects a rating star with the following code, but the performance is very poor (it is a part of huge MUI components).

I am wondering if I can achieve the same effect with `IconContainerComponent`. Is that possible?

```
<Tooltip title={labels[ratingTooltipValue !== -1 ? ratingTooltipValue : 1]}>
<Box display="inline-block">
<Rating
   value={parseInt(field.value, 10)}
   onChange={(newValue) => {
      field.onChange(newValue);
   }}
   precision={1}
   size="small"                                       
   readOnly={viewMode}
   onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
      setRatingTooltipValue(newHover);
   }}

/>
</Box>
</Tooltip>
```

Performance example

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/priceless-feather-w3rrpf?file=%2Fdemo.tsx%3A12%2C18

***EDIT*** I added a 2-second delay inside the `onChangeActive` and now it seems much better. As an alternative solution, can I use a custom tooltip inside the `IconContainerComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here is the answer

```
const TOOLTIP_LABELS = {
   1: 'Useless',
   2: 'Poor',
   3: 'Good',
   4: 'Very Good',
   5: 'Excellent',
};
.....

<Rating
   value={rating}
   onChange={(newValue) => {
      setNewRating(newValue);
   }}
   precision={1}
   size="small"                                              
   onChangeActive={(event, newHover) => {
    const tooltip = document.getElementById(`label-onrate`);
    if (newHover !== -1) {
       tooltip.innerHTML = TOOLTIP_LABELS[newHover];
       tooltip.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
       tooltip.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
 }}
/>
<div className="tooltip">
   <span className="tooltiptext" id={`label-onrate`} />
</div>
```

and the CSS file

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  width: 120px;
  top: -60px;
  left: 50%;  
  margin-left: -100px;  

  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;  
  background-color: white;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
 
  
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1300;
}

/* arrow */
.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; 
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
}
```